# Microsoft Edge - Things seems to be missing

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

In Microsoft Edge, where is the *Help* menu?

Can you turn on Menus? (e.g. File, Edit, View, Favorites, Tools, Help)

Does the Status Bar exist in Microsoft Edge and if so, how does one turn it on at bottom of Edge window?

Comment: I think they tried to make Edge _different_. IE11 is still on Windows 10 if you wish to have those features.

Comment: Edge is, frankly, somewhere between immature and a train wreck. It's missing a number of features I use every day - things like RSS support, cookie filtering, ad/tracking blocking, Flash blocking, last-used tab switching order, and so on - and there are lots of other people who want those features too. The feedback pages for Win10 are largely Edge, and the Edge ones are mostly about all the missing features that make it barely better than a phone browser.

Comment: This is not a bad question. I've seen "broken" applications in my time where certain menus and features went missing or hiding. But in this case (Edge being what it currently is), the features you're talking about, it's all *by design*. Don't forget Edge is a work-in-progress, so things may change over time.

Answer (score 4):

None of these things are "missing" in the sense that they're supposed to be there and are just missing from your copy.  You may be of the opinion that they should be there, but that's another story.

Edge doesn't have traditional "File", "Edit", "View", etc. menus.  It's not alone in that as Chrome on Windows doesn't either.

The only status bar Edge has is the tooltip that appears when you hover over a link, which is also like Chrome.